# C# Convert LinkedList of tuples to Array of tuples

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list, type-conversion

I have the following linked list:

```
private LinkedList<Tuple<string, string>> textList = 
  new LinkedList<Tuple<string, string>> ();
```

The linked list consists of an *unknown number* of elements.

I want to convert this linked list to an *array of tuples*. I tried using the `CopyTo()` method:

```
Tuple<string, string>[] array;
textList.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

But this does not seem to work, here I get the **run time error:**

> Use of unasigned local variable 'array'

Am I using the right approach or is there another way to do it?

Comment: *Linq*? `Tuple<string, string>[] array = textList.ToArray();`

Comment: Your current `CopyTo` approach doesn't work because you never instantiate the array to copy to. You would need to do `Tuple<string, string>[] array = new Tuple<string, string>[size]`, which means knowing how large the array has to be upfront. Using `ToArray`, as @DmitryBychenko suggested, is easier

Comment: Note also that both `LinkedList` and `Tuple` probably shouldn't be used. It's normally better to use a ValueTuple than a `Tuple`, and the cases where `LinkedList` is actually better than the alternatives are few and far between

Comment: How does ValueTuple, differentiate from a regular Tuple? I choose a Linked List since I wanted to be able to add elements in constant time for an unknown number of elements.

Comment: ValueTuple is a value type which was introduced in C# 7, so they avoid too many object allocations. There's special syntax for declaring them, and you can name each element (e.g. `(string foo, string bar)`). `LinkedList` normally performs worse than you'd expect (caches are funny things...), so it's worth always benchmarking a `LinkedList` solution against one using a `List<T>`, etc

Comment: Okay thank you I will probably benchmark using List<T> as well. Just started leaning C# after learning F# in CS where linked lists seemed to peform really well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using *Linq* ([`.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.toarray?view=netframework-4.8)) and let .net create the array for you:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private LinkedList<Tuple<string, string>> textList = 
  new LinkedList<Tuple<string, string>>();

...

Tuple<string, string>[] array = textList.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution i ended up using